# Ignoring cast fail from JSArray to List<String>

Tags: angular, dart

I receive json from api with string array. Then I set it to local variable with type List.

```
if (json['x'] is List) {
  List<String> x = json['x'];
  print(x);
}
```

When I run application, Chrome show me a warning: "Ignoring cast fail from JSArray to List"

What should I do with that?

---

- Angular 5.0.0-alpha+6
- Chrome 63.0.3239.132
- Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.32.0

Comment: I assume this is from DDC, right? dar2js for Dart2 is work in progress. I guess it will be only relevant if the warning is shown there as well. See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/9ee735b659ea0097197ff857ca7debe579e483bd/pkg/dev_compiler/tool/input_sdk/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart#L428-L451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON encodes all arrays as `List<dynamic>`, since that is the specification.

If you want to cast something to `List<String>`, you can't rely on just an implicit cast like you did in Dart 2. You must either use the real type:

```
List x = json['x'];
```

Or use the `.cast` function:

```
var x = (json['x'] as List).cast<String>();
```

I realize that is more writing than before. You might want to look at JSON serialization package such as `json_serializable` or `built_value` if you don't like the boiler-plate around this.