# Dart 2.X List.cast() does not compose

Tags: dart

The upcoming Dart 2.X release requires strong typing. When working with JSON data we must now cast `dynamic` types to an appropriate Dart type (not a problem). 
A related question [Ignoring cast fail from JSArray to List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148759/ignoring-cast-fail-from-jsarray-to-liststring) provides the answer to use the `.cast<String>()` function. Also a recent group messages says the same:
[Breaking Change: --preview-dart-2 turned on by default](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/H8dDhWg_c8I).

The problem is that the `.cast()` function doesn't seem to compose. This original code when compiled using DDC and run in the Chrome browser:

```
Map<String, dynamic> json = { "data": ["a", "b", "c"] };
List<String> origBroken = json["data"].map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
```

Now receives the runtime warning (which will soon be an error)

```
Ignoring cast fail from JSArray to List<String>
```

So I add the `.cast<String>()` as the documentation and related link suggest and still receive the warning:

```
List<String> docFixBroken = json["data"].cast<String>().map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
List<String> alsoBroken = List.from( (json["data"] as List).cast<String>() ).map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
```

The code that doesn't give the warning requires a temporary variable (and also seems to be able to skip the explicit cast):

```
List<String> temp = json["data"];
List<String> works = temp.map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
```

So how can I write the cast and map as a single composed expression? The reason I need it as a single expression is that this expression is being used in an initializer list to set a final class variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote [Ignoring cast fail from JSArray to List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148759/ignoring-cast-fail-from-jsarray-to-liststring), so let me try and help here too!

> So I add the `.cast<String>()` as the documentation and related link
> suggest and still receive the warning:
>
> ```
> List<String> docFixBroken = json["data"].cast<String>().map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
> List<String> alsoBroken = List.from( (json["data"] as List).cast<String>() ).map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
> ```

Unfortunately, `List.from` does not persist type information, due to the lack of generic types for factory constructors (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26391). Until then, you should/could use `.toList()` instead:

```
(json['data'] as List).toList()
```

So, rewriting your examples:

> ```
> List<String> docFixBroken = json["data"].cast<String>().map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
> List<String> alsoBroken = List.from( (json["data"] as List).cast<String>() ).map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
> ```

Can be written as:

```
List<String> notBroken = (json['data'] as List).cast<String>().map((s) => s.toUpperCase()).toList();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks that works when I corrected a typo by adding "().map" after the ".cast<String>".

Comment: I played with your `.toList()` solution and found that I needed to cast `as List<String>` not just `as List`. So this also works `(json["data"] as List<String>).toList().map(...`

Comment: Specifying the type to the mapping function parameter allows the `as List` to work `(json["data"] as List).toList().map( (String s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();`