# Why an explicit ".cast<>()" function in Dart instead of "as <>"

Tags: dart

In my question [Dart 2.X List.cast() does not compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539879/dart-2-x-list-cast-does-not-compose) the answer requires converting a `List<dynamic>` to a `List<String>` as such:

```
List<String> ls = (json['data'] as List).cast<String>().map((s) => s.toUpperCase()).toList();
```

My experience from other languages had me write this first:

```
List<String> ls = (json['data'] as List<String>).map((s) => s.toUpperCase()).toList();
```

Note that this compiles but fails at runtime in Dart 2.

Why does Dart typecasting for a `List` require a function `as List).cast<String>()` as opposed to simply using the Dart `as` "typecast operator" such as `as List<String>`?

---- Edit ----

I am using the most recent Dart 2.0.0-dev.43.0 and get inconsistent runtime behavior with `as` typecasts/assertions. Isn't the `.cast<>()` function creating a new iterable the same as a `.map()`? Changing my code to this works:

```
List<String> ls = (json['data'] as List).map((s) => (s as String).toUpperCase()).toList();
```

This seems to take advantage that the first cast to `List` is a `List<dynamic>`. Thus the `.map` function parameter is also a `dynamic`.

My second example above with to `as List<String>` works in some places in our code but not others. Note that IntelliJ correctly infers the types in all of the above examples - it's the runtime where the failure happens. I'm guessing that the inconsistent behavior is due to Dart 2.x being still in development.

---- 2nd Edit ----

Here are my test cases that I have in one of my class constructors:

```
Map<String, dynamic> json = { "data": ["a", "b", "c"] };

//List<String> origBroken = json["data"].map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();

// Sometimes works - sometimes gives "Ignoring cast fail from JSArray to List<String>" at runtime!!!
List<String> wonky = (json["data"] as List<String>).map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
print("Wonky $wonky");

List<String> fix1 = (json["data"] as List).cast<String>().map( (s) => s.toUpperCase() ).toList();
List<String> fix2 = (json["data"] as List).map( (s) => (s as String).toUpperCase() ).toList();
List<String> explicit2 = (json["data"] as List<dynamic>).map( (dynamic s) => (s as String).toUpperCase() ).toList();

// From accepted answer of the linked question - compile error because .cast() doesn't take parameters
//   error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
//List<String> notBroken = (json['data'] as List).cast<String>((s) => s.toUpperCase()).toList();
List<String> notBrokenFixed = (json['data'] as List<String>).cast<String>().map((String s) => s.toUpperCase()).toList();
```

The problem is the warning `Ignoring cast fail from JSArray to List<String>` sometimes given by the `wonky` assignment. When I say sometimes it's because it changes unpredictably as I make changes to the main application that uses the library that contains this code - without making changes to this class or even the library.

At the time I wrote the first edit above, `wonky` wasn't working. I just tried it again now and it's working. I have not changed any code in this library - I have been working in the main application which has a dependency on this code's library.

Some background, this is a multi-library project being converted from Angular/Typescript. These test cases are based on the processing we do to deserialize JSON into Dart classes. We map JSON (dynamic) strings into various data structures such as enums, Option<> and Either<> (from dartz) using class constructor initializers.

A couple weeks ago the runtime warning started happening I believe because of [Breaking Change: --preview-dart-2 turned on by default](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/H8dDhWg_c8I).
I understand that this warning will soon be an error. So I traced the warning back to these conversions that map from JSON dynamic data (Yes, dynamic data is an edge case in Dart but it's what `dart:convert` provides).

We are developing on Mac using DDC with the most recent Dart 2.0.0-dev.43.0, angular 5.0.0-alpha+8, build_runner 0.8.0, IntelliJ 2018.1 and running on Chrome 65.0.3325.181.

---- Final Edit ----

There is an instability in the current development build/runtime that is behind this issue. No, I don't have a reproducible example. Changing and rebuilding our main app will cause this code in an unmodified library dependency to sometimes give the runtime warning `Ignoring cast fail from JSArray to List<String>`.

The suspect code from the original part of this question (also `wonky` above)

```
List<String> ls = (json['data'] as List<String>).map((s) => s.toUpperCase()).toList();
```

casts the dynamic JSON data to a `List<String>`. The types are fully constrained and the Dart analyzer/IntelliJ infers `s` to be `Static type: String`.

The runtime warning that sometimes occurs and related answers to use `.cast()` is what led to this question. At this time I'll believe the analyzer and ignore the runtime warning.

Comment: "works in some places in our code but not others." can you please provide concrete examples where itßs not working and what the concrete error is?

Answer (score 37):

In Dart 2 generic types are reified.

`as ...` is more like an assertion, if the values type doesn't match `as` causes a runtime exception.

`cast<T>()` is a method introduced in Dart 2 on `Iterable` that actually creates a new iterable of type `Iterable<T>` (or in your case the subclass `List<T>`) filled with the values of the original interable.

---

**Update**

You can use `print('wonky: ${wonky.runtimeType}');` to see what the actual type is.

If the type matches your requirement, you can use `as` to communicate it to the analyzer that it's safe to assume this type.

If the type doesn't match, for example because it is `List` instead of `List<String>`, then you can use `.cast<String>()` to actually make it a `List<String>`.

```
List<String> broken = (json['data'] as List)
  .cast<String>((s) => s.toUpperCase()).toList();
```

Here you seem to try to use `cast` for casting and mapping, but that is not valid.
`map()` can do both though

```
List<String> notBroken = (json['data'] as List)
  .map<String>((s) => s.toUpperCase()).toList();
```

Comment: Sorry for including the `notBroken` code in my example. That code using `cast` like `map` was provided by @matanlurey in answer to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539879/dart-2-x-list-cast-does-not-compose?answertab=votes#tab-top . I had it commented out with the compile error above it.

Comment: I had troubles figuring out what exactly you can't make work. Did my update help you understand the difference between `as` and `cast<T>()` and `map<T>(...)`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. See my "Final Edit" above. I don't have an issue with the "difference between" (Scala development). I've been having trouble with inconsistent build/runtime behavior. Yes, I know I'm on the bleeding edge.

Comment: I think U understand now You could try `implicit-cast: false` in `analysis_options.yaml` to constrain more what the analyzer accepts.

Comment: Also, note that according to the Effective Dart guide, "DON’T use `cast()` when a nearby operation (like `List<T>.from()`) will do." That is because the `cast()` method returns a lazy collection that checks the element type on every operation. If you perform only a few operations on only a few elements, that laziness can be good. But in many cases, the overhead of lazy validation and of wrapping outweighs the benefits. ~ source: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-cast-when-a-nearby-operation-will-do