# How to map and get data from List<Object> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, object, mapping

I'm using CarouselSlider package and the items I used is from a hardcoded data. I'd like to get data from mapping it from a `List<Object>`. Here is my object:

```
    final List<Object> imgListObject = [
      {"image": "/imageAsset1", "text": 'Text 1'},
      {"image": "/imageAsset2", "text": 'Text 2'},
      {"image": "/imageAsset3", "text": 'Text 3'},
    ];
```

And this is how I intend to get the data:

```
    final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgListObject
        .map(
          (data) => Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset(data['image']),
              Text(data['text']),
            ],
          ),
        )
        .toList();
```

I have this error from `data['image']` and `data['text']`:

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
```

My full code:

```
class HowItWorksScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HowItWorksScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ContentSession contentSession = Provider.of<ContentSession>(context, listen: false);

    final CarouselController _carouselController = CarouselController();

    final List<Object> imgListObject = [
      {"image": AppGlobalVariables.howItWorksSliderImage1, "text": 'Text 1'},
      {"image": AppGlobalVariables.howItWorksSliderImage2, "text": 'Text 2'},
      {"image": AppGlobalVariables.howItWorksSliderImage3, "text": 'Text 3'},
    ];

    final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgListObject
        .map(
          (data) => Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset(data['image']),
              Text(data['text']),
            ],
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
        child: AppbarMain(),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CarouselSlider(
            carouselController: _carouselController,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              viewportFraction: 0.8,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlay: true,
              height: 400,
            ),
            items: imageSliders,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async => Navigator.pushNamed(context, landingScreenRoute!),
            child: Text(contentSession.stringsHomeScreen.signin),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

I'm hoping to have this output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is obvious:

```
  final List<Object> imgListObject = [
  {"image": "/imageAsset1", "text": 'Text 1'},
  {"image": "/imageAsset2", "text": 'Text 2'},
  {"image": "/imageAsset3", "text": 'Text 3'},
];
```

is a `List` of `Object`'s, so when you later call:

```dart
Column(
            children: [
              Image.asset(data['image']),
              Text(data['text']),
            ],
```

it can't access `data['image']` since it thinks it's an `Object` not a `Map`.

You'll have to explicitly cast the type. you can do so using the `as` keyword:

```dart
final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgListObject.map(
      (item) {
        Map<String, String> data = item as Map<String, String>;
        return Column(
          children: [
            // using the `!` operator to assert that the value is not null
            Image.asset(data['image']!),
            Text(data['text']!),
          ],
        );
      },
    ).toList();
```

---

Or as an alternative, specify the correct type for `imgListObject`:

```dart
final List<Map<String, String>> imgListObject = [
      {"image": "/imageAsset1", "text": 'Text 1'},
      {"image": "/imageAsset2", "text": 'Text 2'},
      {"image": "/imageAsset3", "text": 'Text 3'},
    ];
```

##### See also

- [What does the "as" keyword do in Dart language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789048/what-does-the-as-keyword-do-in-dart-language)
- [The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'. Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245865/the-operator-isnt-defined-for-the-class-object-dart)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to extract that, with patterns:

```
const List<Object> imgListObject = [
  {'image': '/imageAsset1', 'text': 'Text 1'},
  {'image': '/imageAsset2', 'text': 'Text 2'},
  {'image': '/imageAsset3', 'text': 'Text 3'},
];

List<Column> columns() => [
      for (final item in imgListObject)
        Column(
          children: switch (item) {
            {
              'image': final String image,
              'text': final String text,
            } =>
              [
                Image.asset(image),
                Text(text),
              ],
            final v => throw Exception('what is $v'),
          },
        ),
    ];
```