# A value of type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Iterable<int>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know if this was happening before my switch to the beta channel in Flutter but I don't understand why this is an error. A List is an Iterable right? I took the example from the [official docs](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#what-is-an-iterable).

```dart
Iterable<int> example() {
  Iterable<int> iterable = [1, 2, 3];
  return iterable;
}
```

VSCode marks the list with a red underline telling me:

```
A value of type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Iterable<int>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Iterable<int>'. dart(invalid_assignment)
```

Comment: Correct, Lists are Iterable. I think the error is somewhere in your VS Code.  The example() method you provided works both in Dart Pad and VS Code for me.

Comment: @BeefPapa you were right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem but I tried removing the Flutter and Dart extensions from VSCode, restarting the whole computer and installing them again (in that order) and now the same code works!

As [BeefPapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12592935/beefpapa) said in a comment, the code was absolutely correct.

Who knows what happened.

Answer (score 2):

You need convert again the results to List adding .toList() in the end because Dart changes the type of the variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `as` is more of an assertion and not a cast. To perform the cast you need to use the `.cast` function:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html

E.g.

```
# ...
.toList().cast<Iteratable<File>>()
```

You can read more from this answer covering when/why to `cast`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49542401/931209

Alternatively, you can probably call the `iterator` property on the list (but the above is likely the more correct solution):

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Iterable/iterator.html