# Difference between List<String>.from() and as List<String> in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have read a snapshot from Firebase, and am trying to extract the value from a node that is a list of strings.

When I do this:

```
List<String> answers = snapshot.value["answers"] as List<String>;
```

With the above I get a runtime error saying:

> type `'List<dynamic>'` is not a subtype of type `'List<String>'` in type cast

But somehow these two approaches below both work:

```
List<String> answers = List<String>.from(snapshot.value["answers"])
```

Or this:

```
List<String> answers = snapshot.value["answers"].cast<String>()
```

What is the difference between the first and the other two constructs, and why can't I cast the `List<dynamic>` to a `List<String>` with the `as` casting operation?

Comment: please reference this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49542401/2179571

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's examine some examples:

```dart
var intList = <int>[1, 2, 3];
var dynamicList = intList as List<dynamic>; // Works.
var intList2 = dynamicList as List<int>; // Works.
```

But:

```dart
var dynamicList = <dynamic>[1, 2, 3];
var intList = dynamicList as List<int>; // Fails at runtime.
```

What's the difference?

In the first example, `intList` has a static type of `List<int>`, and the actual runtime type of the object is also `List<int>`. `dynamicList` has a static type of `List<dynamic>` but has an actual runtime type of `List<int>` (it's the same object as `intList`).  Since the object was originally a `List<int>`, it is impossible for the `List` object to hold anything but `int` elements, and casting back to `List<int>` is safe.

In the second example, `dynamicList` has a static type of `List<dynamic>` and an actual runtime type of `List<dynamic>`.  Since the object is initially constructed as a `List<dynamic>`, non-`int` elements could have been added to it, and casting to `List<int>` is not necessarily safe.  You therefore instead must create a new `List` (or `List`-like) object that casts each *element* individually, which is exactly what `List.from` and `List.cast` do.