# flutter convert argument type Object? to parameter type Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but even with the suggestions in the other posts I cannot get it solved... I have a class `Score` that I want to load from a Firebase backend using Flutter. Here is what the `Score` class looks like:

```
class Score {
  final String name;
  final List<String> tags;

  Score(this.name, this.tags);

  Score.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'] ?? '',
        tags = json['tags'] ?? [''];
}
```

Now I am loading this from Firebase using a `Streambuilder<QuerySnapshot>`, code snippet:

```
List<Score> scores = snapshot.data!.docs
                .map((e) => Score.fromJson(e.data()))
                .toList();
```

This leads to the error `The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`. If I try to cast `e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>` as suggested in other posts, the whole app crashes at startup.

Could someone please help me how to convert the snapshot data to a `List<Score>`? Thx!

Comment: What is the exact type of `e.data()` Object?

Comment: ```
Object? data() ; 

package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart ; 

Contains all the data of this document snapshot.

Copied from DocumentSnapshot.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know you're getting a map from the database, you can cast the `Object` to such a `Map` with:

```
Score.fromJson(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)
```

---

To convert the tags to a `List<String>` requires a different kind of conversion:

```
List<String>.from(json['tags'])
```

To learn more about why this is a different type of conversion, see [Difference between List<String>.from() and as List<String> in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221824/difference-between-liststring-from-and-as-liststring-in-dart)

Comment: tried that, but then the app crashes at runtime saying "_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>')" (referring to the tags line in the Score class)

Comment: That's a different error, but I added it to my answer too.

Comment: fantastic, that works! I tried the latter method too, did not work, and I've discarded it as a viable solution... only to see now that my argument between the parentheses contains an error... so your solution is 100% helpful and on the go I learned something on different sorts of casting too... thanks!!