# FLUTTER The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from firebase and an error has occurred.

this is the code :

```
  late final dref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  late DatabaseReference databaseReference;
  showData(){
    dref.once().then((snapshot){
      print(snapshot.snapshot.value);
    });
  }

@override
void initState(){ 
  super.initState();
  databaseReference = dref;
}

child: 
                Container(  
                  height:300,
                  child: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 2, 
                    crossAxisSpacing: 12, 
                    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                    childAspectRatio: 1.30,
                    children: [
                      FirebaseAnimatedList(
                        shrinkWrap:true,
                        query: databaseReference,
                      itemBuilder: ( BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot, Animation animation, int index){  
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(snapshot.value!["intime"]),
                          subtitle : _parkingslot(name:'Floor'),);
                      }),
```

it has an error. That '[' got a red underline and the sentence is :
Returns the contents of this data snapshot as native types.
The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

I've tried to add '!' and '?.' but still got an error, but the sentence is :
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

please help

Comment: There's not enough code here to understand what's going on.  We can't see what `snapshot` is in this case.  Please edit the question to show enough code that someone could take it and reproduce the problem.

Comment: already fixed the code, sorry

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `snapshot.value` is a `Map`, since it is declared as returning an `Object?`. If you *know* for certain that it returns a map, you'll have to tell the compiler about that by casting the result:

```
itemBuilder: ( BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot, Animation animation, int index){  
  var map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value! as Map); // 
  return ListTile(
    title: Text(map["intime"]),  // 
    subtitle : _parkingslot(name:'Floor'),);
}),
```

Also see:

- [Get Map<String, dynamic> from Map<dynamic, dynamic> flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412968/get-mapstring-dynamic-from-mapdynamic-dynamic-flutter/71229970#71229970)
- [How do you cast data from Firebase to a fully typed Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70586105/how-do-you-cast-data-from-firebase-to-a-fully-typed-map/70586158#70586158)
- [how to get value from map in firebase database flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71467457/how-to-get-value-from-map-in-firebase-database-flutter/71469207#71469207)
- [How to pull snapshot key & values into list through Map<>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027043/how-to-pull-snapshot-key-values-into-list-through-map/71027098#71027098)