# How to convert List<List<dynamic>> to List<List<String>> without using iterables in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a 2d dynamic list which is being read from a json file and want to convert it into a 2d string list.

```
CurrentPuzzle({
    List<List<String>> letterMat = const [],
  })  : _letterMat = letterMat;

factory CurrentPuzzle.fromJSON(dynamic jsonData) {
    return CurrentPuzzle(
      letterMat: List<List<String>>.from(jsonData['current_puzzle']['_letterMat']),
    );
```

Data is being read from a json file

```
{
  "current_puzzle": {
    "_letterMat": [
      ["z", "b", "a"],
      ["c", "d", "e"],
      ["f", "g", "h"],
      ["i", "j", "k"]
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried using

```
List<List<String>>.from(jsonData['current_puzzle']['_letterMat'])
```

but run into an error of:

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>')
```

Anysort of help is appreciated!

Comment: Please include `2d_dyn_list` in your question

Comment: Remember don't declare variables starting with a number

Comment: @Jungwon did the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of your code this is just a guess. But try:

```
final newList = 2d_dyn_list.map((o) => o.map((i) => i.toString()).toList()).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it under the premise that I mapped `json data`.

```
final map = {
    "current_puzzle": {
      "_letterMat": [
        ["z", "b", "a"],
        ["c", "d", "e"],
        ["f", "g", "h"],
        ["i", "j", "k"]
      ]
    }
  };

List<List<String>> letterMat = const [];
    letterMat = List<List<String>>.from(map['current_puzzle']!['_letterMat']!);
    print(letterMat); //[[z, b, a], [c, d, e], [f, g, h], [i, j, k]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `from`, try this:

```
factory CurrentPuzzle.fromJSON(dynamic jsonData) {
    return CurrentPuzzle(
      letterMat: jsonData['current_puzzle']['_letterMat'] as List<List<String>>,
    ); // [["z", "b", "a"],["c", "d", "e"],["f", "g", "h"],["i", "j", "k"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using
>
> ```dart
> List<List<String>>.from(jsonData['current_puzzle']['_letterMat'])
> ```

That would work only if the sublists each has a `runtimeType` of `List<String>`.  As stated by [the `List<E>.from` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/List.from.html):

> All the elements should be instances of `E`.

The elements are of type `List<dynamic>`, which is not a subtype of `List<String>`. (Related: [Difference between `List<String>.from()` and `as List<String>` in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67221824/))

You instead need to create a new `List` and to use `List.from` (or alternatively `List.cast`) on each sublist.  For example:

```dart
var listOfDynamicLists = [
  <dynamic>['foo', 'bar'],
  <dynamic>['baz', 'qux'],
];

var newList = [
  for (var sublist in listOfDynamicLists) sublist.cast<String>(),
];
```