# Return list works with from only "Dart"

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to get list from function()
when i direct return this list i get an error
while when i fill it first with List.from it works fine
and this is an Example

/// This Make an Error "IDE" don't print errors just stop compiling tree

```
  static List<Event> get eventList => cacheImpl.get('HiveBoxName');
```

/// This Working Fine

```
  static List<Event> get eventList2 => List.from(cacheImpl.get('HiveBoxName'));
```

[image: Example]

.

and the get method that i call is
[image: Get Mthod]

**so why it works only with List from ?**

Comment: Please add the source code of the class from which you have created the cacheImpl instance. add the error which you are getting

Comment: i had edit the example to be more clear

Comment: But you have pasted the same code as image

Comment: cachImp is only call the hive implementation that gets your local data

Comment: what type of data does ``cacheImpl.get('HiveBoxName')`` return

Comment: you can't assign a different type of data to a type of list.

Comment: but it works when i used List from and passes to it an list

Comment: Presumably there's a type error where `cacheImpl.get` does not return a `List<Event>`, and `List.from` works because it performs type casts.  It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong without the exact error message, which you haven't shown.

Comment: @jamesdlin becouse IDE dont provide msg error ,, but yes it works with casting only
the question why it dont work with casting " as List<Event> " ?

Comment: If the IDE doesn't provide an error message, how do you know it's failing?  As for `as List<Event>`, see: [Difference between casting with 'cast' method and 'as' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70959115/)

Comment: Because i told you the compiler dont coplete debugging tree
But your link is helpful ,,, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**try converting return type to list**

```
get<List<T>>(String key, T defaultValue) {
```

Comment: yes I did and didn't work

Comment: can you show the function code that is being called.

Comment: i had edit the question with it

Comment: try updated answer

Comment: it generic function you may use it to return object not list

Comment: although we need to think about the reason not about answer because i know the answer but need to know the reason

Comment: because you are returning dynamic object T it is supposed to be list of T so dart can identify it as list.

Comment: But even when i parsed it as List it didnt work

Comment: can you show error ?

Comment: compiler stope without errors