# what is cast<R>() method in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I hope you are fine,
I read about the `Set<R> cast<R>()`  method in Dart's [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-core/Set/cast.html), but I was unaware of both his description and his application

can anyone explain more complete and understandable?

Comment: Does this help? [Difference between casting with 'cast' method and 'as' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70959115/)

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for the guidance but I saw this link before, but the explanations were unclear to me

Comment: `.cast` performs a runtime cast for each element of the collection.  Can you elaborate about what you're specifically confused about?

Comment: Yes sure
For me, the question is why when we convert a Set of String to a Set Int type does not convert values to int and when we use RuntimeType to understand that value it shows us an error?

Comment: You cannot cast (whether using `as` or using `.cast`) to convert a `Set<String>` to `Set<int>`. `String` and `int` are not related types.  If you want to apply such a conversion, you would need to do: `var intSet = {for (var element in stringSet) int.parse(element)};` or `var intSet = stringSet.map((element) => int.parse(element)).toSet();`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you really for your good description, I mistakenly thought that when using CAST conversion, the values inside the SET would be converted, but with your explanations I realized that it was not and only the SET type would change and the values remain in the same form, Thank you very much your description helped

Answer (score 4):

Generic collections in Dart are always typed by the data they can contain, such as `List<int>`, `Set<String>`, or `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. This is all well and good, but because of how generics work in Dart, you can't always simply cast a collection of one type into another type. For example, this code will throw an error at runtime:

```dart
List<dynamic> foo = [1, 2, 3];
List<num> bar = foo as List<num>; // Error: List<dynamic> is not a subtype of List<num>
```

Instead, we have `cast` methods, which instead of casting the entire collection, will loop through the collection casting all of the elements within to the desired type, resulting in a collection of that type.

```dart
List<dynamic> foo = [1, 2, 3];
List<num> bar = foo.cast<num>();
```

Note that, like a normal cast, the `cast` method will throw an error if any of the elements in the collection aren't compatible with the target type.