# dart socket.on method type casting problem

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, socket.io

[image]

How can I type casting data from socket. I want to get rid of dynamic list but it doesn't accept any type casting.

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: I don't know what package `SocketHelper` comes from, but see [Difference between casting with 'cast' method and 'as' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70959115/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> and make sure parameter e is a String value

```
final onlineUsersList = onlines.map((e)=> e.toString()).toList();
```