# List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast when i try to fetch data from api

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, express, dart

```
Future<List<Product>> fetchAllProducts(BuildContext context) async {
final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
List<Product> productList = [];
try {
  http.Response res =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('$uri/admin/get-products'), headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'x-auth-token': userProvider.user.token,
  });

  httpErrorHandle(
    response: res,
    context: context,
    onSuccess: () {
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonDecode(res.body).length; i++) {
        productList.add(
          Product.fromJson(
            jsonEncode(
              jsonDecode(res.body)[i],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  );
} catch (e) {
  showSnackBar(context, e.toString());
}
return productList; }
```

I am trying to create a ecommerce app . When i try to run the above api i get "List' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast" error . How can i solve this?

Comment: paste your json or use QuickType to make your model hopefully it will solve your problem

Comment: You haven't explained exactly where you're getting that error, and I don't see `List<String>` in your code.  However, you probably should read [Difference between casting with 'cast' method and 'as' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70959115/)

Answer (score 1):

Before gointo other parts if you will check status of the response good. and try bellow code segment.

```
Future<List<Product>> fetchAllProducts(BuildContext context) async {
  final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
  List<Product> productList = [];
  try {
    http.Response res = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('$uri/admin/get-products'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'x-auth-token': userProvider.user.token,
      },
    );

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> productsJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
      productList = productsJson.map((productJson) {
        return Product.fromJson(productJson);
      }).toList();
    } else {
      
      showSnackBar(context, 'Failed to fetch products: ${res.statusCode}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    showSnackBar(context, 'Error: $e');
  }
  return productList;
}
```