# Object List can't be null and I can't use cast because it's null in Flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, for-loop, casting, null

I'm trying to pass a List in a loop to retrieve the strings and show them in a button, and this is happening:

```
      final List<Map<String, Object>> perguntas = [
      {
        'texto': 'Quantos anos o Britto tem?',
        'Respostas': ['22', '21', '23'],
      },
      {
        'texto': 'Britto é viado?',
        'Respostas': ['Sim', 'Não', 'Sim e não'],
      },
      {
        'texto': 'Qual o jogo favorito do Britto?',
        'Respostas': ['Dark souls', 'Elden Ring', 'Assassins Creed', 'Trove'],
      },
      {
        'texto': 'De onde o britto é?',
        'Respostas': ['Tangamandápio', 'Favela do rio', 'Alphaville', 'SP'],
      }
    ];
    var respostas = [];
    for (String textresposta in perguntas[question_changing]['Respostas'].cast()) {
      respostas.add(textresposta);
    }`
```

It gives me: `The method cast can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'`

So I do this: `for (String textresposta in perguntas[question_changing]['Respostas']!.cast())`

And it gives me: `The method cast isn't defined for the type Object, try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining the method cast`

I tried passing a map to a loop and the code says it's null and I can't use NullSafety because cast doesn't work with it to convert the variable.

If I remove cast, I get an type error: "The type 'Object' used in the 'for' loop must implement 'Iterable'.

Comment: Any use of Map.[] can result in null.  You can iterate over the entries of the map, which will give you key/value pairs.

Comment: 1. As mentioned `Map` lookups might fail, and the compiler has no way of knowing that.  You therefore must always check for `null`. 2. Your `Map` is of type `Map<String, Object>`.  Values that you get out of it therefore are known only to be `Object`s.  Any method that doesn't exist on the base `Object` type therefore cannot be called without an explicit downcast: `(perguntas[question_changing]['Respostas'] as `List<String>).cast()`. 3. Calling `cast()` with an explicit type argument is fairly pointless.  The `as List<String>` cast probably does what you want anyway.

Comment: Also see [Difference between casting with 'cast' method and 'as' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70959115/).

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting `.cast()` as `as List`

```
 final List<Map<String, Object>> perguntas = [
      {
        'texto': 'Quantos anos o Britto tem?',
        'Respostas': ['22', '21', '23'],
      },
      {
        'texto': 'Britto é viado?',
        'Respostas': ['Sim', 'Não', 'Sim e não'],
      },
      {
        'texto': 'Qual o jogo favorito do Britto?',
        'Respostas': ['Dark souls', 'Elden Ring', 'Assassins Creed', 'Trove'],
      },
      {
        'texto': 'De onde o britto é?',
        'Respostas': ['Tangamandápio', 'Favela do rio', 'Alphaville', 'SP'],
      }
    ];
    var respostas = [];
    for (String textresposta in (perguntas[question_changing]['Respostas'] as List)) {
      respostas.add(textresposta);
    }
     print(respostas);
```