# Flutter/Dart List.firstWhere() error at list of subclass

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list like this.

```dart
final List<SuperType> list = <SubType>[ ... ];
```

then, I want something like this works.

```dart
final element = (list as List<SuperType>).firstWhere(
  (e) => ...ANY CONDITION...,
  orElse: () => const SuperType(),
);
```

but ends with this error.

```
Expected a value of type '(() => SubType)?', but got one of type '() => SuperType'
```

just wonder how to fix it. I'm using Flutter 3.13.9.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70963189/.  `list as List<SuperType>` doesn't change the runtime type of the object (the cast does nothing since `list` is *already* declared to be a `List<SuperType>`).  Since the runtime type of the object is a `List<SubType>`, its `firstWhere` method expects an `orElse` argument that returns a `SubType`.  Replacing `list as List<SuperType>` with `list.cast<SuperType>()` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
void main() {
  final List<SuperType> list = [SubType(a: 10, b: 20), SubType(a: 2, b: 30)];
  final element = list.firstWhere(
    (e) => e.a == 2,
    orElse: () => SuperType(a: 20),
  );
  print(element.a); //2
}

class SuperType {
  final int a;

  SuperType({required this.a});
}

class SubType extends SuperType {
  final int b;

  SubType({required super.a, required this.b});
}
```

We have `SuperType` as parent and `SubType` as child class. The `list` variable casts the list of `SubType`s to a list of `SuperType`s. Then we can find the object we want in the list.

Comment: I thought there's already being some cast done, but seems it actually doesn't.
what i was actually doing was -> 
   `<List>SubType sublist = [ SubType(a: 10, b: 20) ];`
   `<List>SuperType list = sublist;`
and that occurs some error... but this one just works fine ->
   `<List>SuperType list = [ ...sublist];`
maybe the type cast not works on first expression.. and I think I can figure it out my own. thanks.