# Getting type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<...>' error in JSON

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm decoding a response body and I'm getting the error:

```
'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Example>'
```

I'm parsing a JSON array of JSON objects, one of the fields is a list of objects as well and I suspect my issue stems from that. I am also using the json_serializable library. Below is my code, I omitted some fields out and changed some variable names but it represents the same code:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'example_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Example {

  (some fields here)
  final List<Random> some_urls;
  final List<String> file_urls;


  const Example({
    (some fields here)
    this.some_urls,
    this.file_urls,

  });

  factory  Example.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ ExampleFromJson(json);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Random {
  final String field_1;
  final int field_2;
  final int field_3;
  final int field_4;
  final bool field_5;

  constRandom(
      {this.field_1, this.field_2, this.field_3, this.field_4, this.field_5});

  factory Random.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$RandomFromJson(json);
}
```

from the .g dart file that json_serializable made (ommited the encoding part):

```
Example _$ExampleFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Example(

      some_urls: (json['some_urls'] as List)
          ?.map((e) =>
      e == null ? null : Random.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          ?.toList(),
      file_urls: (json['file_urls'] as List)?.map((e) => e as String)?.toList(),

}

Random _$RandomFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Random(
      field_1: json['field_1'] as String,
      field_2: json['field_2'] as int,
      field_3: json['field_3'] as int,
      field_4: json['field_4'] as int,
      field_5: json['field_5'] as bool);
}
```

This is my future function:

```
  Future<List<Example>> getData(int ID, String session) {
    String userID = ID.toString();
    var url = BASE_URL + ":8080/example?userid=${userID}";
    return http.get(url, headers: {
      "Cookie": "characters=${session}"
    }).then((http.Response response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var parsed = json.decode(response.body);
        List<Example> list = parsed.map((i) => Example.fromJson(i)).toList();
        return list;
      }
    }).catchError((e)=>print(e));
  }
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This code creates a `List<dynamic>`

```
parsed.map((i) => Example.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

You must explicitly cast `List<dynamic>` to `List<Example>` like so,

```
List<Example> list = List<Example>.from(parsed.map((i) => Example.fromJson(i)));
```

or just

```
var /* or final */ list = List<Example>.from(parsed.map((i) => Example.fromJson(i)));
```

See also

- [In Dart, what's the difference between List.from and .of, and between Map.from and .of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50320220/in-dart-whats-the-difference-between-list-from-and-of-and-between-map-from-a)
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/List/List.from.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/List/List.of.html
- [Dart 2.X List.cast() does not compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539879/dart-2-x-list-cast-does-not-compose)

Comment: I get the error type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Example>'

Comment: Try `.from(...)` instead of `.of(...)`. I'm still reading up and try to understand  what exactly the difference between `of()` and `from()` is.

Comment: Seems `of` expects the input list to have the correct generic type already, while with `from` only the elements in the list need to be of the correct type.

Comment: Your answer saved me from pulling out all my hair in frustration. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 15):

**Reason for Error:**

You get this error when your source `List` is of type `dynamic` or `Object` (let's say) and you directly assign it to a specific type without casting.

```
List<dynamic> source = [1]; 
List<int> ints = source; // error
```

---

**Solution:**

You need to cast your `List<dynamic>` to `List<int>` (desired type), there are many ways of doing it. I am listing a few here:

1. ```
   List<int> ints = List<int>.from(source);
   ```
2. ```
   List<int> ints = List.castFrom<dynamic, int>(source);
   ```
3. ```
   List<int> ints = source.cast<int>();
   ```
4. ```
   List<int> ints = source.map((e) => e as int).toList();
   ```

Comment: @maheshmnj Which cast and on the basis of which Dart version you're saying that?

Comment: please refer this https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/736

Comment: @maheshmnj Can you please share the link of the particular thread which supports your initial statement -- cast is no longer available to use.

Comment: please take a look at this I think I may have mis understood the statement based on the comments for this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245597/8253662

Answer (score 4):

I was receiving the `'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Example>` when i tried Günter's solution.

```
 var parsed = json.decode(response.body);
 var list = parsed.map((i) => Example.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Casting the parsed data into a `List<dynamic>` (rather than just letting it go to `dynamic`) resolved that issue for me.

```
 var parsed = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
 var list = parsed.map((i) => Example.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```dart
var parsed = json.decode(response.body);
List<Example> list = parsed.map((i) => Example.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Can be replaced with this code:

```
import 'package:json_helpers/json_helpers.dart';


final examples = response.body.jsonList((e) => Example.fromJson(e));
```

And everything will work as you expected...