# Flutter Convert List subtype

Tags: dart

I want list subtype to another subtype how can i?

```
List<type1> someList = new List<type1>();
```

I want convert this list to

```
List<type2> someList = new List<type2>();
```

I have both model with same string its possible? i try this

```
 List<type2> tList = new List();
 for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
     tList.add(snapshot.data[i]);
 }
```

error:

```
type 'type1' is not a subtype of type 'type2'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<...>' error in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886683/getting-type-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-list-error-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

```
final someList = <TypeA>[];
final convertedList = List<TypeB>.from(someList);
```

A simple example would be:

```
final numList = <num>[1, 2];
final intList = List<int>.from(numList);
```

You might run into errors, if your `num` contains a `double`, in that case, you can use `map`:

```
final numList = <num>[1, 2.0];
final intList = numList.map((e) => e.toInt()).toList();
```

Comment: Sorry its not just list ..its dynamic list

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62013459/6618622) out then