# dart/flutter casting dynamic list from Future.wait causing type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<CustomClass>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, casting, future

Acquiring some data in my application is done using [`Future.wait<T>`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-async/Future/wait.html). An issue is it only works with one datatype, thus running a few futures in it with datatypes will result in you having to cast each result in the return result list into its appropriate types.

The issue I'm facing starts by `Future.wait`, specifically handling multiple results from the `Future`.

Signatures of function used below, for context:

```
Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ProfileConversationPreference>>> getProfileConversationsOnce({String? uid});
```

**Future call:**

```
var result = await Future.wait<dynamic>([
  //...
  profileService.getProfileConversationsOnce(uid: uid), // 6
  //...
]);
```

When the future returns, to get the `getProfileConversationsOnce`'s result, I need to use `result[6]` (the result' index)

#### Problem:

To assign the result to the appropriate List, I need to cast it from a `List<dynamic>` to a `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ProfileConversationPreference>>`. According to [this notable SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539879/dart-2-x-list-cast-does-not-compose), one should use a [`cast<>()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html) function.

When using this cast in one function, it doesn't work and throws the following error:

```
conversationList = (result[6] ?? []).cast<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ProfileConversationPreference>>().map((e) => e.data()).toList();
```

**Error:**

> ```
> I/flutter (12257): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ProfileConversationPreference>'
> ```

BUT when breaking up this cast, it works correctly:

```
  List s = (result[6] ?? []);
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ProfileConversationPreference>> ss = s.cast<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ProfileConversationPreference>>();
  conversationList = ss.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
```

---

**More details:**

Sample of the code I'm running:

```
List<ProfileConversationPreference> conversationList = [];
try {
 // this works, at each step I can view the content and it is processed correctly - it is a broken up version of the single line below
  List s = (result[6] ?? []);
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ProfileConversationPreference>> ss = s.cast<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ProfileConversationPreference>>();
  conversationList = ss.map((e) => e.data()).toList();

  // this does NOT WORK
  conversationList = (result[6] ?? []).cast<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ProfileConversationPreference>>().map((e) => e.data()).toList();
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Comment: we don't cast like this

Comment: @nitishk72 how does one cast then?

Comment: show me this class ProfileConversationPreference

Answer (score 0):

Solution inspired from this link ([github dart-lang issues](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/736)) addressing an issue: **Effective Dart: When to use "as", ".retype", ".cast"**

Thus, I made use of [`List<T>.from()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/List/List.from.html).

**Solution**

```
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<ProfileConversationPreference>>.from(result[6] ?? []).map((e) => e.data()).toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

... or you could cheat a little bit:

```
List<ProfileConversationPreference> conversationList = [];

await Future.wait([
  //...
  () async { 
       conversationList = await profileService.getProfileConversationsOnce(uid: uid); 
  }(),
  //...
]);
```

If you can do that for all your futures, you can just skip the result array and the casting.

Comment: doing that for 9 futures felt...wrong - but yet, you are right